# Function NLFILTER expected its first input, A, to be two-dimensional

Tags: image, matlab

when i write this codes in MATLAB(script)

```
I=imread('f:\oli.tif');
I2=nlfilter(I,[3 3],'std2');
imshow(I2)
```

gives these following errors :

```
Error using iptcheckinput
Function NLFILTER expected its first input, A, to be two-dimensional.

Error in nlfilter>parse_inputs (line 134)
iptcheckinput(a,{'logical','numeric'},{'2d'},mfilename,'A',1);

Error in nlfilter (line 51)
[a, nhood, fun, params, padval] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in Untitled21111111 (line 2)
I2=nlfilter(I,[3 3],'std2');
```

whats wrong?

Comment: no , im sure its correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test it here, but if I can recall correctly the parameter to nlfilter must be a grayscale image, and maybe the one you're passing is rgb.

Try:

```
I=imread('f:\oli.tif');
I2=nlfilter(rgb2gray(I),[3 3],'std2');
imshow(I2)
```